# Infrared stream from kinect (v1) c #

Tags: c#, image, kinect, infrared, pixelformat

This is the kinect for xbox 360, using the kinect.dll library.
No problem with the `RgbResolution1280x960Fps12` or `RgbResolution640x480Fps30` color stream.
The problem occurs with the infrared stream (`InfraredResolution640x480Fps30`)
Below is the code used and the resulting image.

```
 using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            byte[] colorData = null;

            if (colorFrame == null) return;

            if (colorData == null)
                colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];

            colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(colorPtr);
            colorPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(colorData.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(colorData, 0, colorPtr, colorData.Length);

            if (ir)  //ir is true if there is infrared stream
            {
                kinectVideoBitmap = new Bitmap(
               colorFrame.Width / 2,  //stream in 16 bit
               colorFrame.Height,
               colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb,  //probable error
                colorPtr);
            }
            else
            {
                kinectVideoBitmap = new Bitmap(
               colorFrame.Width,
               colorFrame.Height,
               colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb,
                colorPtr);
            }


            pic.Image = kinectVideoBitmap;  //pic is picturebox

            byte[] pixelData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
            colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
```

An error could be the handling of the `PixelFormat`, indicated in the code, but I don't think it depends only on that. Below are the image derived from my code, and the one that generates the example app "`kinect explorer`".
(both images are screenshots)

[This is the image of the Kinect explorer example app, you can see how well defined it is in quality and noise, more importantly, even distant objects are well seen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa0bi.jpg)

[This is the image of my app, in addition to the various colors deriving from the wrong pixelformat, the noise is such that you cannot see any of the distant objects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37pq3.jpg)

Do you have ideas on how to fix and get a clean image?
I thank everyone in advance.

Comment: Open both images with notepad.  There is an ASCII header in the image the indicates the format.  I suspect the format is different in your code from the clean image.

Comment: Both images are screenshots, even if they were different formats I don't think they can affect the photo so much. I am not an expert on the subject but the two photos have completely different characteristics of visibility and depth, it would make me think that there is some processing to do, perhaps through the kinekt library.

Comment: See following webpage.  the last screen show how to see the current display mode : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45203bf5-496d-4e6e-9db8-75535833d70a/red-mark-on-quotgraphic-processorquot-and-quotverify-kinect-depth-and-color-streamsquot?forum=kinectv2sdk.  Compare the Kinect explorer example with your image.